# ValueError when running Deep learning Model: "Data is expected to be in format..."

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am new to deep learning scope and I ran across this issue that I dont understand why it was initiated.

```
raise ValueError(error_msg)
ValueError: Data is expected to be in format `x`, `(x,)`, `(x, y)`, or `(x, y, sample_weight)`, found: (array([[[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.
```

Traceback

```
'data_params': {'data_types': ['local_box', 'local_surround', 'pose', 'box', 'speed'], 'data_sizes': [(15, 512), (15, 512), (15, 36), (15, 4), (15, 1)]}, 'count': {'neg_count': 737, 'pos_count': 363}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "implementation/Model2/test_new.py", line 75, in <module>
    test_model(saved_files_path=saved_files_path)
  File "implementation/Model2/test_new.py", line 66, in test_model
    acc, auc, f1, precision, recall = method_class.test(beh_seq_test, saved_files_path)
  File "/home/implementation/Model2/action_predict.py", line 1114, in test
    test_results = test_model.predict(test_data['data'][0],
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1579, in unpack_x_y_sample_weight
```

Code
The train and test sets are the same

```
test_results = test_model.predict(test_data['data'][0],
                                          batch_size=8, verbose=1)

 history = train_model.fit(x=data_train['data'][0],
                                  y=None if self._generator else   data_train['data'][1],
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  epochs=epochs,
                                  validation_data=data_val,
                                  class_weight=class_w,
                                  verbose=1,
                                  callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: please review [mre]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have modified my question. I would appreciate your help